# Setting start time for to.period in R

Tags: r, xts

I have a data set containing trade-by-trade data. The data is not evenly spread out (trades take place randomly). I would like convert the data to 10 minute increments using to.minutes10. Is there a way to make the generated data start on the hour? Currently R is simply using the first observation as the starting point and then taking 10 increments from there. I would like to start at say 07:00 and then have the next one 07:10, 07:20, etc. It seem pretty obvious there should be an option, but I can't find it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have changed the original question to deal with only one data set as I see my question was ambiguous. I don't want to merge the data sets. I just want to compare them, so that they both start at 07:00.

Comment: One way can be to create a dataframe of date-time in the format you require and then just merge all the data frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `floor_date` from lubridate to achieve this. Just set the unit to what you need it to be.

```
index(my_xts) <- lubridate::floor_date(index(my_xts), unit = "10 mins")
```

Comment: This does what you want, but you should be very careful when you timestamp data that occurred during the period at the beginning of the current period. It's much better to timestamp it with the beginning of the *next* period.

Answer (score 2):

Your question sounds like you want to align at the *beginning* of the period. This can be dangerous because it gives your data a timestamp that is *before* it actually occurred. That can introduce look-ahead bias, depending on what you're doing with your data.

You can use `align.time()` to change the index to the beginning of the next period.

For example:

```r
x <- .xts(1:10, sort(1595862429+runif(10, 100, 3600)))
head(m <- to.minutes10(x), 2)
##                     x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close
## 2020-07-27 10:17:56      1      3     1       3
## 2020-07-27 10:25:45      4      5     4       5
head(a <- align.time(m, 60*10), 2)
##                     x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close
## 2020-07-27 10:20:00      1      3     1       3
## 2020-07-27 10:30:00      4      5     4       5
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the forward looking bias? How does this misalign the timestamp and the timing of the actual trade?

Comment: @coolhand: if you change `10:17:56` to `10:10:00`, that means your data says that at 10:10:00, you knew what would happen 8 minutes in the future. Knowing the future makes predicting it a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways though it is a bit lengthy and doesn't involve `xts`.

```
dates <- data.frame(Date= seq(as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 07:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 14:00:00"), by= "10 mins"))

df1 <- data.frame(Date= seq(as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 08:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 12:00:00"), by= "10 mins"), Trade1= 1:25)

df2 <- data.frame(Date= seq(as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-07-25 12:00:00"), by= "10 mins"), Trade2= 101:113)

df <- merge.data.frame(df1, merge.data.frame(dates, df1, by.x= "Date", by.y= "Date", all.x= TRUE), by.x= "Date", by.y= "Date", all.x= TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you.  see my question was ambigous :-) Sorry! I just want to know if I can start one data set at a particular point.